# JSOUP in Android Studio for Web Scrapping

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I have having issue to web scrap data from this simple link:

https://translatekreol.mu/translation.php?&source=enn%20bon%20garson&lang=kreol&boutton=Translate

There is only the body tag to scrap but JSOUP library is not showing any result. The website is taking around 25seconds to load and despite timeout is 60000

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://translatekreol.mu/translation.php?&source=enn%20bon%20garson&lang=kreol&boutton=Translate").timeout(60000).get();
```

is not working. But if we scrap google.com instead of above url, it works.

The website: https://translatekreol.mu/translation.php?&source=enn%20bon%20garson&lang=kreol&boutton=Translate is slow, so I increase the timeout to see if it can collect data but did not work.

The response of this website is from body tag, so despite getting data, the application stops at this point.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Either increase the number or set it to zero:

```
....timeout(0).get();
```

A timeout of zero is treated as an infinite timeout.

Comment: The answer was that http and https website are different and should add in manifest and settls(False)